# What is EXT4-fs error (device md0): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:739: group 10770, 0 clusters in bitmap, 32768?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, ubuntu-12.04, ext4

On my Ubuntu Server 12.04 I got this errors (via dmesg):

```
[ 1104.544121] EXT4-fs error (device md0): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:739: group 10771, 0 clusters in bitmap, 32768 in gd
[ 1104.549227] EXT4-fs error (device md0): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:739: group 10772, 0 clusters in bitmap, 32768 in gd
[ 1151.872640] EXT4-fs error (device md0): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:739: group 10784, 28639 clusters in bitmap, 28640 in gd
```

I have absolutely no idea why these errors are showing up.

My server configuration:

- 1 x SATA HDD for the OS
- 4 x 2TB SATA HDD (device **md0**): RAID 5 on EXT4

Possible sources of the errors:

- I (or the system automatically) did a [resync](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Resync), because one SATA cable was damaged.
- I copied some files from an external hdd with NTFS to the EXT4 Raid system (but this shouldn't be a problem I guess).

I googled, but didn't found a solution.
I may try:

- The command fsck (can't provide link, because of superuser.com spam protection..) to repair something? Maybe it helps...
- Wait for a solution on this [Linux Kernel Bug entry](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.ext4/30575)

Comment: Okay I think the resync and fsck command fixed the problem. The errors do not show up again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try umounting the disk and running fsck on it. What does this command show?

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

Your disks should be in sync so you can repair the filesystem.

Comment: Okay I think the resync and fsck command fixed the problem. The errors do not show up again.

Comment: Could you please expand on the `mdstat` matter? I have solved my filesystem error message at my Kali Linux on Raspberry by fscking, but I have no such `/proc/mdstat` file (well, it is a Raspberry version).

Comment: /proc/mdstat is a status file for the mdadm multi-disk-admin package used for managing RAID. Unless you're doing something very un-ordinary, you have no RAID on a raspberry pi, and this doesn't apply. The advice is simply to be sure that the RAID array's data is synced between the drives before attempting a filesystem level repair.

Comment: You've second guessed and didn't answer answer the question. The question is what does the message mean, why is it happening. Instead you're telling how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

> These messages are due to ext4 detecting a mismatch in the free block
>   count between the ext4 buddy allocator bitmaps and the free block
>   count in the group descriptor. This may be the result of corruption of
>   the bitmaps. In the case of a mismatch, the code will update the group
>   descriptor free block count with the calculated value from the bitmaps
>   to ensure they match going forward. The exact cause of this issue is
>   still under investigation in private Bugzilla, but the cause in remote
>   storage situations appears to be hardware/firmware related in a
>   majority of the cases.

source: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/155873